# Comment dit-on "software programming" et "software testing" en francais?

Tags: expressions, informatique

Pour « software programming », je ne suis pas sûr laquelle des deux expressions suivantes est correcte :

> programmation de logiciel

ou

> programmation deS logicielS.

Pour « software testing », j'ai trouvé deux solutions :

> essai des logiciels

et

> test des logiciels

(une fois encore, je ne suis pas sûr si la version correcte du logiciel soit singulière ou plurielle).

Si quelqu'un peut m'expliquer pourquoi on choisit l'un et pas l'autre, ça serait bien apprécié !

Comment: [test](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(informatique)) est plus répandu que *essai*

Comment: Aussi, je dirais que les _essais_ (plutôt côté utilisateur) viennent après les _tests_ (plutôt côté développeur).

Answer (score 6):

Contrairement à *software* qui est indénombrable et qui n'existe donc qu'au singulier en anglais, *logiciel* est dénombrable en français. Le pluriel est donc plus indiqué dans les expressions citées car on ne programme ou ne teste pas « du logiciel » mais « des logiciels » :

*Software programming*  → « **Programmation de logiciels** », ou tout simplement « Programmation ».

*Software testing* → « **Tests de logiciels** », voire « **Tests logiciels** » où logiciel est utilisé comme un adjectif, c.f. http://www.cftl.fr/cf-tl/a-propos-du-cftl/

Programmation des logiciels et test des logiciels sont aussi possibles, mais dans ce cas, il s'agira plutôt d'un ensemble prédéfini et précis de logiciels, par exemple :

> Programmation et test des logiciels embarqués sur le satellite de télécommunication.

Note: Le développement de logiciels représente l'ensemble des activités conduisant à la création de nouveaux logiciel. L'une de ces activités, appelée programmation, consiste à utiliser des langages de programmation pour convertir des algorithmes et fonctionnalités en code source. Il ne s'agit que d'une étape intermédiaire. Il arrive souvent que l'on confonde programmation et développement. Une raison est probablement que les métiers précédemment spécialisés et hiérarchisés (programmeur → analyste-programmeur → développeur) sont aujourd'hui généralement tous regroupés et unifiés, et que la dénomination retenue est celle de développeur.

Comment: Le terme de programmation est pratiquement obsolète dans les métiers de l'informatique, aujourd'hui. On parle plutôt de développement.

Comment: MakorDal « Programmation » est encore couramment utilisé. Ce terme est plus spécialisé que développement, il ne viendrait à pas grand monde l'idée de dire « développement (orienté) objet », « développement fonctionnel », « langage de développement » au lieu de « programmation fonctionnelle, orienté objet et langage de programmation ». Il est cependant vrai que l'on parle beaucoup moins aujourd'hui de « programmeurs » ou « analyste programmeurs » pour mettre l'ensemble de ces métiers sous la dénomination de « développeurs ».

Comment: Je lis la note et me pose alors la question de ce que recouvre _software programming_: _programmation_ ou _développement_?

Comment: @Mouviciel Programmation [de logiciels]. Préciser « de logiciels » n'est utile que si le contexte ne permet pas de la distinguer de la programmation de spectacles (cinéma, théâtre,etc.), d'enregistrements audio/video, de machines à laver le linge, la vaisselle et autres radiateurs. Dans toutes ces activités, on programme indubitablement quelque chose mais il serait abusif de dire que l'on a développé quoi que ce soit.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui... Et non. Citer des concepts qui ont 30 ans pour montrer que le terme programmation n'est pas en train de devenir obsolète, dans un monde qui court après les évolutions n'est pas un argument. A la limite on pourrait parler de Programmation extrême... Sauf que personne ne traduit Extreme Programming, là où Développement Agile est effectivement utilisé.

Answer (score 4):

Pour *Software Programming*, *Programmation de logiciel* serait le plus adapté, ou alors *Programmation informatique* dans un sens plus large.

Pour *Software Testing*, le plus naturel serait *Test logiciel*.

Cf. [linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=software%20programming) pour avoir un contexte d'utilisation.

Les traductions de titres d'[articles Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmation_informatique) peuvent aussi t'aider.

Comment: Le terme de programmation est pratiquement obsolète dans les métiers de l'informatique, aujourd'hui. On parle plutôt de développement.

Answer (score 4):

Dans les milieux de l'informatique, on parle beaucoup plus de *développement* que de *programmation*. J'entend souvent **développement logiciel**, où *logiciel* est utilisé comme adjectif.

Pour le test, je dirais plutôt **test de logiciel**, bien que les expressions habituelles parlent plus de vérification, d'intégration ou de validation, comme dans **validation logicielle**, qu'on distingue de la *validation matérielle* ou de la *validation système*.

Comment: La "programmation" à repris un sens de planification dans ces métiers. On utilise aussi le terme de "recette" pour les tests.

Comment: @MakorDal La recette (ou acceptation) n'est qu'une partie des tests effectués sur le logiciels, il s'agit des tests effectués par l'acquéreur du logiciel pour vérifier qu'il est bien conforme à ses attentes. Il existe de nombreux autres types de tests, de robustesse, de charge, fonctionnels, unitaires, d'intégration, de non régression, etc.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai, mais le vocable vaut quand même la peine d'être mentionné.